# C# Query String and x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: c#, forms, ashx

I have an ashx processing POST of a form on my website.
Most of the time, I am sent data with content-type `x-www-form-urlencoded`.

If my user is under IE8/9, I have to use `XDomainRequest` object instead of the usual `XmlHttpRequest`.

In the first case, I use `context.Request.Form["..."]` to read the datas, but `HttpRequest.Form` is only populated if content-type is `x-www-form-urlencoded`.

In the IE8/9, `XDomainRequest` only support plain/text content-type, hence I'd have to use `HttpRequest.Querystring` to get the datas.

My question is : Is Querystring populated when the content type is `x-www-form-urlencoded` ?